# What are some ideas for determining the color of LEDs using opencv?

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, colors, python-3.5

I am trying to determine the color of some LEDs.  I want it to be 100% accurate in determining the color, and it is to be automated in deciding the color.  What are some ideas for how to do this with a webcam and python 3.5?

My idea was to take the average hsv values, background lighting value, and mode of the hue in a vector, train a machine learning algorithm to determine whether the color is green red or off, and then use the trained model to determine the color in the future.  The problem is, it doesn't seem to be working with 100% accuracy.  Any ideas why it isn't as precise as I wanted it to be?  Any ideas of what I should do to improve my code?  The thing is I can't just use histograms because when the background lighting changes, the "color" of the LED changes too (according to the webcam, if you know what I mean).

Thanks for the help!

My process for determining the color for now:

1. find the LED locations
2. set the LEDs' color and collect data
3. create a dataset and then use dataset to train SVM, KNN, and Forest
4. once the colors have changed and now I want to use the webcam to determine the color, I load the model, and use SVM, KNN, and Forest to determine the color. If 2 or more agree, then I know what the color is.

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8uCJ.jpg), [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmKDQ.jpg), [image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDMtj.jpg)

Comment: One approach is to use color thresholding using `cv2.inRange()`. This would give you a mask of the color output, then use `cv2.countNonZero()` to determine if any pixels with that color range were detected. From there, you can have a hash table that stores various colors and determine the color from there. Adding your input image would help!

Comment: I added some images of what I'm working with!

Comment: And thanks!  I'll look into that method!